# How Pytorch do row normalization for each matrix in a 3D Tensor(Variable)?

Tags: torch, pytorch, tensor

If I have a 3D Tensor (Variable) with size [a,b,c].
consider it as a b*c matrix, and I hope that all these a matrix got row normalized.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `normalize` function.

```
import torch.nn.functional as f
f.normalize(input, p=2, dim=2)
```

The `dim=2` argument tells along which dimension to normalize (divide each row vector by its `p-norm`.

Comment: I tried but the row sum is not 1. Thank you though.       
I also tried renorm function, it also does not work.

Comment: Do you mind updating the question with details of a minimum working example which fails to give the output? I will be in a better position to amend then.

Comment: @QinqingLiu if you want row sum equal to 1 (L1 norm) you can set set `p=1`, this answer sets the sum of squares to 1 (L2 norm).

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as f

a, b, c = 10, 20, 30

t = torch.rand(a, b, c)
g = f.normalize(t.view(t.size(0), t.size(1) * t.size(2)), p=1, dim=1)
print(g.sum(1)) # it confirms the normalization

g = g.view(*t.size())
print(g) # get the normalized output vector of shape axbxc
```

Answer (score 0):

To normalize a matrix in such a way that the sum of each row is 1, simply divide by the sum of each row:

```
import torch
a, b, c = 10, 20, 30
t = torch.rand(a, b, c)
t = t / (torch.sum(t, 2).unsqueeze(-1))
print(t.sum(2))
```